# dj-stripe (django) - How to distinguish between free trial vs. paying user?

Tags: django, stripe-payments

How do you distinguish between a user who is on free trial vs. someone who is actually paying?

Say it's a 30 day trial.. but someone decides to upgrade on day 10... so you can't go by date.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check the status on the Subscription to distinguish whether a user is currently on a trial. If the Subscription has `status: trialing` that means they are currently in a trial. If the Subscription is `active` that means the Subscription's latest invoice has been successfully paid. There are other statuses as well like `past_due` and `unpaid`, that mean the Subscription is still in place but isn't necessarily in a good standing to be provisioned (like maybe payment on the latest Invoice hasn't been made yet).

You can see a full breakdown of what each status means in Stripe's docs: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#subscription-statuses